# RethinkDB indexing two fields with time

Tags: javascript, indexing, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have `RethinkDB` with data/table let say "news" with huge number of data row :

```
[
  {
    "author": "author1",
    "category_id": "business",
    "country": "id",
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 15 2018 09:26:52 GMT+07:00",
    "description": "description",
    "id": "74c25662-7f94-47ef-8a7e-5091924819a9"
  },

  {
    "author": "author2",
    "category_id": "business",
    "country": "id",
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 15 2018 09:26:52 GMT+07:00",
    "description": "description2",
    "id": "74c25662-7f94-47ef-8a7e-5091924819a9"
  },

  {
    "author": "author3",
    "category_id": "sport",
    "country": "id",
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 15 2018 09:26:52 GMT+07:00",
    "description": "description3",
    "id": "74c25662-7f94-47ef-8a7e-5091924819a9"
  },

  {
    "author": "author3",
    "category_id": "business",
    "country": "id",
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 15 2018 09:26:52 GMT+07:00",
    "description": "description4",
    "id": "74c25662-7f94-47ef-8a7e-5091924819a9"
  }
  .....
]
```

I need to create index for `category_id` and `created_at` (`timestamp`) and query for certain category and filter by day now (certain date) only. I want to optimize and speed up for query result

I can do it in `javascript` by filter like this for `category_id` `business` and `day` 15 :

```
r.table("news").filter({category_id: 'business'}).filter(
    r.row("created_at").day().eq(15)
)
```

But how I can create index for `category_id` and `created_at` and query it by certain day of `created_at`.

```
r.table("news").indexCreate( ???
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
r.table('news').indexCreate('businessAndDate', function (doc) {
  return doc('category_id').add(doc('created_at').day().coerceTo('string'));
});
```

Then you can:

```
r.table('news').getAll('business15', {index: 'businessAndDate'})
```

You may want to insert a separator between the data (like `'business-15'`), and use more than just the day (otherwise, why bother having a full timestamp?), that's up to you and how many `.add` you're willing to write. ;)
According to [the reference](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/index_create/), this is called an arbitrary index.